# Django: MySQL no such table: aidata.django_session

Tags: django, django-models

I'm running Django 1.4 on Windows 7 in Pycharm and I installed WAMP because I need to have my data in a MySQL table.

This is from setting.py

```
DATABASES = {
  'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'aidata',
    'USER': 'root'
   }
}
```

From installed_apps I uncommented:

```
'django.contrib.sessions'
```

Running *`manage.py syncdb`* does not create any tables ( even models) in my mysqldb.

I get the error when trying to acces `/admin/`

```
 DatabaseError at /admin/
(1146, "Table 'aidata.django_session' doesn't exist")
```

Comment: What's the output from syncdb?

Comment: what does your settings.INSTALLED_APPS look like, too? And if you're using South, what does ./manage.py migrate --list show?

Comment: snycdb  outputs Creating tables ... Installing cutom SQL Installing indexes ... No fixures found

Comment: INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'intq', #my app name
    'django.contrib.admin',
)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Double check the db credentials
2. make sure you uncommented this line in your middleware:

   MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
       ....
       'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
   )
3. then try to `python manage.py syncdb`.
4. if you are still having issues post any output

### EDIT -- NEXT CHECK:

1. do you have a "django_content_type" table?
2. if so, does that table have a "session" record?
3. if so, delete the session record and try to `python manage.py syncdb`

### EDIT -- STEP 3:

now i'm guessing, post up your settings file so i can make meaningful troubleshooting attempts

1. Stop your server if you have one running
2. go into your file browser and delete the settings.pyc file
3. try to `python manage.py syncdb`

my thought is that a pyc file with the sqlLite info may be cached and not regenerating

### EDIT -- STEP 4:

everything in your settings.py look ok to me. try something for me? create a new django project, don't enable the admin or add in your apps i just want to know if from scratch everything in your django install seems to be working

1. django-admin.py startproject testsite
2. do the database configuration/setup
3. python manage.py syncdb

let me know if the models create properly

Comment: I have that uncommented too. The connecton to db works ( If i change the NAME, it throws "..Unknown database"). snycdb should create this table and othere from models right?

Comment: My database 'aidata' is empty. This is something I forgot to mention earlier - I had sqlite3 before and it was working fine, but now I want to use mysql only ... how do I execute this django 'reinstall'?

Comment: could you post up your entire settings file?

Comment: I deleted settings.pyc and did syncdb and still nothing. Then I deleted the *.db file. syncdb output showed it created all the tables, but stored in the same file name as before and not in the mysql db

Comment: Models created properly in the db:). So it is probably the easiest to start the new project with the old models, views ... The project is somehow 'stuck' to the sqlite.

Comment: glad i could help,  just to double check step 4 solved your problem?

Comment: Yes,creating a new project and snycdb with these db credentials in setting solved the problem.

Comment: I'm running into the same problem right now - did you find an explanation? This is strange...

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same problem and for me (running django 1.7 development trunk of mid-sept.2013) it helped to

1. remove all south migrations (`[app]/migration`)-directories
2. remove south from `INSTALLED_APPS` in settings.py

That might be due to the shift towards the integrated migration system in django v1.7, but I'm speculating here.