# Cannot run python-django application because django cannot create session table

Tags: mysql, django, python-3.4

I cannot run application because Django cannot create table "app.django_session". Using python 3.4, Django Framework and MySQL.
I tried `syncdb` command. I dropped old database and created a new one, after that it doesn't work.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py", line 176, in _get_session
    return self._session_cache
AttributeError: 'SessionStore' object has no attribute '_session_cache'
```

...

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 280, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'app.django_session' doesn't exist")
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10515808/django-mysql-no-such-table-aidata-django-session

Comment: Django>=1.8. @chadu I did all from that tut but it is not working.

Comment: did you used migration?

Comment: Yes, i do. Migrations works with no errors but when i run server getting exception.

Comment: SessionMiddleware is uncommented. What to disable ?

Comment: show the settings.py file

Comment: MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',

)

Comment: If you don’t want to use sessions, you might as well comment the SessionMiddleware line from MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES and 'django.contrib.sessions' from your INSTALLED_APPS.

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27180353/django-project-looking-for-attribute-session-cache

Comment: I am using SessionMiddleware but i want from django to create needed tables.