# Django makemigrations does not create admin databases

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-migrations

I have a django project, this is the installed apps entry in settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'crawler',
]
```

when I run `python manage.py migrate` everything seems to be fine. But when I try to login into django admin page, It says

> (1146, "Table 'stock_db.django_session' doesn't exist")

It seems to me that `migrate` is not creating django admin databases, but why?
I even tried deleting the database, creating it again and running `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`, It didn't create django_session table.

Comment: Did you do ```python manage.py makemigrations``` before ```migrate``` ?

Comment: @Ram Yes I did.

Comment: There is no `stock_db` app provided by Django, your error talks about a table `stock_db.django_session` not existing. And given that there is no `stock_db` app in your `INSTALLED_APPS` the error is not surprising...

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat stock_db is the name of the database.

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10515808/django-mysql-no-such-table-aidata-django-session

Comment: Check this out
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10515808/django-mysql-no-such-table-aidata-django-session

Answer (score 1):

Migrating your models won't create Admin resources. Those need to be created separately in your admin.py. See more details here
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/

Essentially you need to create a Resource class, specify the fields, define whatever  you want:

class MyModelResource(resources.ModelResource):

```
class Meta:
    model = MyModel

fields = [
    "your_fields",
]
```

Finally, you need to register your resource:

admin.site.register(MyModelResource)

Answer (score 0):

Try makemigrations first if it doesnt help continue reading

This type of problem can appear in many situations, most common one is that your migration file system has broken. Reason may be that you tried to edit migration files, or you deleted some of them, or if you work on big teams there may be conflicting migrations. Fixing migrations system takes a lot of time and effort, plus you should know how they work. If project is not in production and you just playing around, I recommend to clear db and delete migration files and run makemigrations and migrate again.
Also be aware if you have multiple apps with models referencing each other with foreign keys or whatever.

Comment: How can I delete the migrations of django admin app?

Comment: migration of admin app resides in python packages directory. but i would not recommend deleting migrations, just delete the migrations of the apps you created

Comment: and this error comes from db not django stock_db is your schema and django_session is a table. it says that there is no table django_session in your database schema "stock_db", look at search path you provided in your django project, and have a look at your database

Answer (score 0):

Always make sure you run **makemigrations** before **migrate**

First run your migrations using below commands:

```
python manage.py makemigrations appname

python manage.py migrate
```

> **If this doesn't work then delete your current migrations using `Python manage.py  squashmigrations` and then re-run migration commands**.

Comment: What is appname for django admin?

Comment: have you tried - `python manage.py makemigrations admin`

Comment: it says `no changes detected in app admin`

Comment: I even tried deleting the database and creating it again, but it didn't work either.